# Changing multiple columns to as.numeric based on column name

Tags: r, lapply

I am looking for an equivalent of this solution:

```
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], as.numeric)
```

but instead of column index `df[4:10]` I am hoping to use column names so smth like `df[c(name1, name2, name3)]`

Any and all help greatly appreciated!
N.

Comment: The tidyverse solution would be to use `across()`. Eg `df <- df %>% mutate(across(c(name1, name2, name3), as.numeric))`. See [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) for details.

Comment: `df[,c('col1name','col2name')] <- lapply(df[c('col1name','col2name')], as.numeric)`  it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
columns_vector <- c("Col1", "Col2")

for (col in columns_vector) {
  df1[col] <- as.numeric(df1[col])
}
```